# How to send request on click of option in autocomplete jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load data on select event of search box which uses autocomplete jQuery.

Here is my code :

```
$(function () {
  window.app.api.sendRequest({
    url: 'myurl that return json',
    method: CI.XHRHelper.HTTP_METHOD.GET,
    success: function (data) {
      // setup autocomplete function pulling from currencies[] array
      $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: data
      });
    }
  });
})
```

The request returns json like:

```
[{"data":"abc","value":"abc-win / 12333"},
{"data":"abcd","value":"abcd-win / 12333"},
{"data":"abcde","value":"abcde-win / 12333"},
.
.
.
{"data":"abcdef","value":"abcdef-win / 12333"}]
```

I want to send request to load data of selected string/text/value.

How do I get select event in this?

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/ i think this is what ur looking for. specify the select event and you can alert the event fired.

Answer (score 0):

Your instantiation of the autocomplete functionality requires a `select:` option.

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: data,
    select: function (event, ui) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $('#someElement').val(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

I think that's what you're looking for, but you may need to clarify some details of the question.

If you mean that you want to call an AJAX request to do something using that string, then I can give you an example in ASP.NET, but I don't know what language you're using:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: data,
    select: function (event, ui) {
         event.preventDefault();
         window.location.href = '/Home/Index/' + ui.item.value;
    }
});
```

That example will redirect you to the your index page, using the value of the selected item as a parameter. If you do not want to be redirected, but instead wish to load the data in a div on the current page, you could do:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: data,
    select: function (event, ui) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/Index',
            type: 'POST',
            data: ui.item.value,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response) {                     
                    $('#someDiv').html(response);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status); alert(thrownError); }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using java. Can u provide fiddle with just alert on select event please??

Comment: It doesn't execute any alert on select event